# Exporting highstock chart data shows data discrepancies

Tags: angularjs, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, highcharts

I am trying to export highstock data to csv/xlsx and also view data table. But I do not get proper data when I download or view data. It exports the chart series data as well as the navigator series data.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container_' + $scope.tileId, {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                allButtonsEnabled: true,
                inputEnabled: true,

                buttons: [{
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 60,
                    text: '1h'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                }, {
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1w'
                }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                }, {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1y'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }]
            },
            chart: {
                width: null,
                marginRight: 100
            },
            title: {
                text: $scope.tileName
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: true
            },
            exporting: {
                chartOptions: {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },},
            yAxis: {
                title: { text: $scope.xAxisLabel }

            },
            plotOptions: {

            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                layout: 'horizontal',

            },
                            series: $scope.seriesOptions
        });
```

I am also using export-data.js as Highstock does not support export to excel directly.

[image: Highstock chart]

data downloaded looks something like this 
[image: Downloaded Data]

Now If I disable the navigator the exported data is correct.

The issue is I need to keep the Navigator enabled and not export the series data in the navigator but only the Chart series data.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/highcharts/export-csv):

> To prevent the navigator in a stock chart, set
>   navigator.series.includeInCSVExport to false.

Like this:

```
navigator: {
    series: {
        includeInCSVExport: false
    }
}
```